# "call on" in academic settings

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

According to [Barron’s TOEFL Flashcards](http://barronsbooks.com/tp/toefl/flashcards/flashcards.html), "call on" means the following:

> **call on:**
>
> *1) to acknowledge in class*
>
> *2) to invite to speak*

However, I cannot understand the usage of the first one in academic settings.

Comment: Please give an example of what you don't understand. It's completely unclear to me what your difficulty is.

Comment: @ColinFine In fact, I don't know how it is used on the first meaning.

Comment: I cannot understand why one should vote to close this question?

Comment: The “unclear what you’re asking” close votes were cast before you told us where those definitions came from. Now that you’ve clarified that, perhaps there won’t be any more confusion, or any more close votes.

Answer (score 1):

It’s not really a “first one” and a “second one”.

The flashcard says:

> **call on**: to acknowledge in class; to invite to speak

It’s not really meant to be two separate definitions, it’s more like one definition worded in two different ways.

I like Wordnik’s the definition listed in Wordnik better: [*to select (a student)*](https://www.wordnik.com/words/call%20on).

So, if a teacher **calls on** a student, that teacher is simply giving the student an opportunity to do or say something. That “something” may vary depending on the situation; one of the most common ways “call on” a student is to have that student answer a question posed by the instructor. A teacher might also “call on” a student to ask a question, particularly if the student has their hand raised.

Comment: But it is usual that two distinct definitions separated by ";" sign.

Comment: I could only find one other flashcard in that set with a semi-colon; that was for **be (get) behind**, and I think it follows same the pattern I’ve provided here, with two related phrasings rather than two disjoint meanings. To be late in an academic setting doesn’t mean "to have a lot of work to do”; it means to fall behind schedule with that work. Also, it’s worth remembering that [flashcards](https://www.etymonline.com/word/flash#etymonline_v_40455) are not designed to provide in-depth meanings; they merely provide terse meanings that are quick to study.